# How do I get StripeToken using stripejs in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am following this [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) on stripe. I have managed to display the card form on the page but when the form submits it does not generate the stripe token. I have tried console.log at various sections but the token appears not to be generated. How do I go about it in generating the token?
This is my code

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('extra-css')

@endsection
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class=" alert alert-info">
                <p>You will be charged ${{ number_format($plan->cost, 2) }} for {{ $plan->name }} Plan</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
                <form action="{{ route('buybids') }}" method="post" id="payment-form">
                    {{--  --}}
                    @csrf                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <label for="card-element">
                                Enter your credit card information
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="card-element">
                            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="{{ $plan->id }}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Pay</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('extra-js')
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_889M8QcUi17G4idk6JlBSete');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#000000'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.on('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
//tried console.log(form); but no response
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.card.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      //tried console.log(result); but no output
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `createToken()` and passing the mounted card Element. The call should be `stripe.createToken(cardElement)` and not `stripe.card.createToken()`

https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement

Comment: I have made the changes and still does not generate the token

Comment: Is there an error message in the console? Can you set a debug breakpoint on the line that says createToken and try to run the code in the console?